# Grove - IMU 9DOF v2.0 with Raspberry Pi for calculating position, compass values

Tags: sensor

I am using Grove - IMU 9DOF v2.0 with Raspberry Pi to calculate the linear displacement, compass values. I followed the code given in [this GitHub URL](https://github.com/FaBoPlatform/FaBo9AXIS-MPU9250-Python). While running the read9Axis.py code (which is given inside example folder) I am not able to get magnetometer values. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps first try 6 dof or 3 dof, or 2dof of single 3dof magneto module, which is 10 times easier to troubleshoot. I will try to help if you switch to 2dof magneto and show me the python listing. My experience with 3dof and 2dof accelero python programming is easy, no need to use any drivers or libraries which might be out of date (say OK for Rpi3 stretch, but no guarantee for Rpi4B buster, and the author no longer supports upgrading :(

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to use only accelerometer values (Raspberry pi 3+) to get precise values.Can you please help me out ...@Glorfindel

Comment: Ah, good, so you have decided to do just accelerometer to start with. Right now I am answering another question also on accelerometer. Could please join in the discussion: (1) 
Rpi Controlling MPU9250 Accelerometer 20 Metres Away
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108441/long-distance-i2c-communication. Cheers.

Comment: Are you using any algorithm like dead reckoning for getting precise values?? @Glorfindel