# Rpi Controlling MPU9250 Accelerometer 20 Metres Away

Tags: i2c, sensor

I am doing a project which require an mpu9250 accelerometer to be connected to a Raspberry pi. Both are kept at a distance of 20m apart. What is the easiest way of data transfer without losses?

Comment: Ah, let me see. MPU9250 talks I2C, so you start with 30cm long I2C wires. If everything goes well, you can extend the wires to 60cm. Usually the impedance reaches the limit of 400pF, and logic signal becomes distorted and noisy,and you start getting transmission error messages Then you can consider using I2C buffers and extenders. If you start with level shifters to talk at 5V, then you can do better. But the whole project is very tricky, not for the faint of heart newbies.

Comment: I would suggest newbies be humble, forget 9-DOF, and start with 2-DOF, perhaps using 3-DOF ADXL345 accelerometer. The good thing with ADXL345 is that you can use either I2C or SPI. SPI can talk louder over longer distance, so you have a second chance when you decide to give up I2C, the learning curve of which is much steeper than SPI. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: I have tried MPU 6050 and ADXL 335. But MPU9250 was better and easier to calibrate. Which way would be easier for a newbie like me, going the wireless way with Esp32 or wired way using extenders or any other wireless communication protocols?

Comment: I²C is designed for short distance inter chip communication preferably on the same board.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I might have misunderstood you question which you did not specify wired or wireless, not to mention if I2C is a requirement. So I would suggest to look at the big picture first.  I have roughly introduced the stumbling blocks of I2C. Perhaps we can sit back to stare at the big picture, and also into the future. I am glad that you suggested ESP32, not the no future ESP8266-12. ESP32 or not, and if ESP32, NodeMCU LUA, which has a very steep learning curve (if not eating can food), or MicroPython, which is only for "small" projects, ...

Comment: I suggest we forget ESP32 for now, the main reason is that the commercially available tools are not mature yet, and only friendly for non industrial developers (I assume you are, like me, not one of those guys, preparing things for the near future, I mean, for the next 5 years). So I would suggest first to look at the wireless world: What to use, if not ESP32? (We can always fall back to ESP32 later) I would suggest to watch this YT and let me know your comments or preferences. No hurry to reply.  Take your time and perhaps like me know other good references. YT next section. / to continue, ..

Comment: Reference YT: Which radio module? NRF24, LoRa, CC1101, HC12, 433MHz, HC05 - 94,981 views 2019jun30
(1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxF1N9asjts. So far I have messed around with BlueTooth serial (HC05), 433MHz (RF12B), Now I am playing with 2,4GHz (nRF24L01p: (2) https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103645/discussion-on-question-by-stevencellist-rpi-spi-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-mod), you might like to google and wiki harder before you make the final decision. Ah, morning tea time.  See you this afternoon or tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: You said the following: “ .   have tried MPU 6050 and ADXL 335. But MPU9250 was better and easier to calibrate ..". But I though MPU9250 actually contains three things, gyro, accelero, and magneto, and accelero inside is actually MCP6250. So if you know MPU9250‘s accelero part, you already know 6050, and vice versa. I did start with MPU9250 and MPU6250 a long while ago, but then I found some problems, including:

Comment: (1) Rpi3B+ cannot adjust I2C speed, but fixed at falt 100kHz. This is fatal, because we need to do I2C block write which requires "bus stretching" which is not available in smBus. One  workaround is lower I2C speed, but Rpi3B+ cannot do that, so I got stuck. Now Rpi4B buster cannot lower speed toeven 10kHz, so problem sovled. But there are other problems, like MPU9250 IMU algortihm is not open, so I gave up and switched to Bosch (See MagPi 84 for more details).

Answer (score 1):

why not use RS485 or RS422 as transfer layer. it will be more reliable, I think wireless can not ensure the stability, if your application has request on that, it's not a good idea. what you need is design a adaptor transfer message from i2c to uart or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

## Magic

It is basically axiomatic that can't achieve "without losses".
The best you can do is reduce them.

Have a CPU local to the MPU9250 that reads the data.
Read it repeatedly to ensure you got the right values.
(Drat.  I forgot to do this!  Time to consider more updates.)

Use a communication link between the local CPU and the controlling PI that uses at least CRC32 for error detection, and includes receipt confirmation and retransmission.
(Note that Ethernet and WIFI both do the former, and TCP does the later.  This can simplify implementation.  But don't feel yourself restricted to these protocols.)

Finally, if you are really paranoid, use redundant devices: two (or more) MPU9250s, local CPUs, power supplies, and communication links.  If you are really really paranoid, even redundant PIs.